# Unit test of a mapping when members are hidden

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, moq

I have to test a projection that handle a given events and persist it on a read only Mongo database (I'm using official c# Mongo Driver):

```
public class MyObjectProjection : IHandleMessages<RegisteredEvent>
{
    private MongoCollection<MyObjectView> _collection;
    private MyObjectView item;

    public MyObjectProjection (MongoDatabase db)
    {
        _collection = db.GetCollection<MyObjectView>("my-object");
    }

    public void Handle(RegisteredEvent message)
    {
        item = new MyObjectView();
        item.Id = message.Id;

        // some code omitted                

        _collection.Save(item);
    }
}
```

I need to unit test the `Handle` method, given that:

- I don't want an integration test. Database and collection are mocked, so the save *is not real*
- I just want to test the item-message mapping
- the members are hidden and I don't want to make them more visibile

Should I use alternative solution rather than reflection or friendly assembly? What is the best practice in a case like this?
Right now my test look like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // ARRANGE - some code omitted
        databaseMock
            .Setup(x => x.GetCollection<MyObjectView>(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(collection);

        collectionMock
            .Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyObjectView>()))
            .Returns(It.IsAny<WriteConcernResult>);

        // ACT
        var handler = new MyObjectProjection(database);
        handler.Handle(evt);

        // ASSERT
        // nothin' to assert here!
    }
```

this works, but i have nothing to assert when `Handle` method is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best practice in a case like this?

The best practice is to make members visible. Is there any particular reason why you need to hide members?

Then, you can assert against argument passed to `Save` method :

```
    MyObjectView objectView;

    collectionMock
        .Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyObjectView>()))
        .Callback<MyObjectView>((obj) => objectView= obj)
        .Returns(It.IsAny<WriteConcernResult>);

    Assert.That(objectView.Id, Is.EqualTo(evt.Id));
    //assert other properties
```

Comment: I prefear to be as restrictier as I can, and I really don't like the idea to increase visibility just for testability sake. What I wanted was exactly this, testing through mock.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `Handle()` method interacts with the collection, by calling the `Save()` method. Therefore you can expect that the element passed to the Handle method has proper ID set:

```
collectionMock.Verify(x=>x.Save(It.Is<MyObjectView>(v => v.Id == 5)), Times.Once,"save should be called with object with Id = 5");
```

I assumed here that the `evt` that is passed into `Handle()` has and Id of 5. Code not tested, but I think something like that would do the trick.

Comment: The ID is the only field that I map manually, all others are AutoMapper stuff, i don't feel comfortable knowing that the only thing tested is the one I trust more than others :)